Model for MySQL 8.0 Stored Procedure
I created a query in MySQL 8.0.
I want to create a Model class for the below query:
call rep_getusercheckinsperday(2024,9,'XXX');
result 1 - 2024-09
call rep_getusercheckinsperday(2024,10,'XXX');
result 2 - 2024-10
the problem is that the rows and also the columns are variable, meaning that in on month I can have 30 days, in other 31 days and I can have 5 or 10 or 15 users.
Note: ASP.NET Core 6.0 (C#) + MySQL 8.0
I tried to create like this:
public class DBGetMyGuidesReportsbyDay
{
    public string User { get; set; } = "";
    public long? Total { get; set; } = 0;
    public string Day { get; set; } = "";
}


You model seems like a List<DBGetMyGuidesReportsbyDay> where every item in the list stands for a day and User should be a Dictionary<string,long?> where the key is the username and the value is .. long pause .. the value.

But why do you that transposing of data in the database and not just return the data in a flat relational standard form and do the transposing in code?

I want to start by pointing out that MySQL isn't really meant to be used in that sort of dynamic fasion. Instead of a variable amount of columns you should consider adopting a static, more strongly typed approach, as demonstrated in MySQL's user guide. Who am I to tell you what you can-and-can't do.. but I'd be remiss however if I didn't at least try to steer you on another path, while you still have the chance.
If, however, you insist on continuing with the dynamic table approach. I'd try to solve this by storing the retrieved data in a dynamic-type object, List<k, v> or Dictionary<k, v>, then iterate over it each entry. In each cycle of that iteration, you'd check if the "entry" (your "column" in this instance) is a user column or not;
..if no) continue
..if yes) Create a new instance of your DBGetMyGuidesReportsbyDay class where the "key" equals the User
Hope it helps!
* Edit, added link to MySQL Docs.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-tables.html
